# Callback with passing data from SwiftUI to UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

How can I send data from SwiftUI view to UIKit ViewController in callback's closure?
Let's say we have SwiftUI View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    var buttonPressed: (() -> Void)?
    @State var someData = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.purple
            Button(action: {
                someData = "new Data"
                self.buttonPressed?()
                
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyView()
    }
}
```

And ViewController where, inside which we have SwiftUI view:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let swiftUIView = MyView()
        let hostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
        self.view.addSubview(hostingViewController.view)
        
        hostingViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hostingViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingViewController.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        hostingViewController.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        hostingViewController.rootView.buttonPressed = {
            print ("callback recived")
            // i know i can try to get the data in this way, but if MyView become too complex than it won't look well
            //print(hostingViewController.rootView.$someData)
        }

    }
}
```

How can I send someData via closure to ViewController?

Comment: just make it non optional, this will generate initializer to which you can pass needed logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass it via argument, like

```
struct MyView: View {
    var buttonPressed: ((String) -> Void)? // << here !!
    @State var someData = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.purple
            Button(action: {
                someData = "new Data"
                self.buttonPressed?(someData)  // << here !!
```

and

```
    hostingViewController.rootView.buttonPressed = { value in // << here !!
        print("callback received")
        print(value)
    }
```